# How can I extract the Sound Pressure Level (dB) from the Sound Pressure (Pa) and plot it versus time?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to [calculate the SPL from the Sound pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure). 
In one measurement I have about 1000000 samples of pressure (computed vs time).

But the problem is, because in the equation in the link the root mean square pressure is used, the result from the 1000000 Pa samples will be 1 value of dB.

I have already tried using in Matlab [a script I found online](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11871-signal-rms) that uses the moving RMS (sliding window technique with overlapping). But I am not sure it is the right way.

```
%How rms function is used:
%rms(signal,window length,number of overlapping,zero padding)

%my calculation with filtered(C-Weighting) Signal and sample frequency of 48000Hz

prms_l=rms((filterC(OUTPUT(:,2),48000)),30000,29900,0); %rms pressure left ear
prms_r=rms((filterC(OUTPUT(:,3),48000)),30000,29900,0); %rms pressure right ear
t_spl=rms(OUTPUT(:,1),30000,29900,0); %time for sliding window

SPL_l=20*log10(prms_l/0.00002); % P_reference(air)=0.00002 Pa
SPL_r=20*log10(prms_r/0.00002);
```

My expected result will be a plot of the SPL versus Time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a moving window average is a good way to do this. I would use a much smaller window though, change its size depending on the frequency content of your signal. Also, don't filter the x-axis values.

The function you found on the File Exchange is not very good. It would be much more efficient to use `conv` to compute the moving average:

```
ws = 101; % window size
prms_l = sqrt(conv(OUTPUT(:,2).^2,ones(ws,1)/ws,'same')); % rms pressure left ear
prms_r = sqrt(conv(OUTPUT(:,3).^2,ones(ws,1)/ws,'same')); % rms pressure right ear
t_spl = OUTPUT(:,1);
```

A weighted window typically gives better results (e.g. create [a Gaussian window](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/22)). Using a Gaussian window you will have no aliasing artifacts in the output. Your code (without depending on my toolboxes) would look like this:

```
sigma = 30; % determines window size, kernel will be 6*sigma+1
ws = ceil(3*sigma);
x = -ws:ws;
kernel = exp(-x.^2/(2*sigma^2));
kernel = kernel / sum(kernel);
prms_l = sqrt(conv(OUTPUT(:,2).^2,kernel,'same')); % rms pressure left ear
prms_r = sqrt(conv(OUTPUT(:,3).^2,kernel,'same')); % rms pressure right ear
t_spl = OUTPUT(:,1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  What I also tried is using the movmean:    
    Tmov=movmean(OUTPUT(:,1),n_block,'Endpoints','discard');
    Out2=OUTPUT(:,2:3).^2;%OUTPUT^2 für Schalldruck
    M_full=movmean(OUTPUT(:,1:3),n_block,'Endpoints','discard');
    P_rms=sqrt(movmean((Out2),n_block,'Endpoints','discard'));
    SPL_lr=20*log10(P_rms/0.00002);  But then my signal starts from 2.5s until t(end)-2.5

Comment: In aeroacoustics there are also many examples where they plotted e.g 5.6kHz octave band A -weighted. Or a 8kHz third octave band(always vs time). Would you know anything about that?

Comment: @ifigeniaasl: The `conv` code produces the same size output as the input. The data at the edges is not correctly weighted here, it's possible to correct that but I didn't know how important that is. `movmean` is OK too, but use `'Endpoints','shrink'` instead of `'discard'` to have the right output size. The octave bands, I presume, determine what filter you use instead of a moving mean -- apply a bandpass filter instead. But I'm not sure this is actually the case, I don't work in that field.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations and your time :)